# carousal jquery is not working in firefox and opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, opera

am using horizontal carousal at the bottom of my page www.woody.my, the carousal works fine using chrome explorer while its invisible using firefox, opera, IE.

Below is the image how it looks in chrome :

[image]

while this how it looks in firefox :
[image]

Comment: can u show your code?

Comment: can you view it using inspect element (chrome) or using Firebug (firefox). its just a css issue.

Comment: Can you include the link to your site?

Comment: my website is www.woody.my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in the HTML

```
<ul style="width: 1000px;">
```

And this one in the CSS line:526

```
.infiniteCarousel ul li {
    background: url("../images/footer_img_box.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 198px;
}
.infiniteCarousel .wrapper ul {
width: 900px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Whilst the position of the `<li>` are absolute, they get stacked on top of each other. Needed to change the position to relative, also the main container had an extremely large size of 9999px, change that to the view port to when the elements are floated left of each other you can see them

Also remove the position on `.infiniteCarousel .wrapper ul` class

Comment: you could also change the width of the ul to be 100%

Comment: Thank you Mehrdad, your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.infiniteCarousel ul li {
    background: url("../images/footer_img_box.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 198px;
}
```

ps I'm in Malaysia too :)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mehrdad, but the carousal appear improper in firefox while its not appearing in chrome.